# Sql Injection - Possible exploitations on a real case

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

This is a snippet of a PHP script:

```
$useragent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : NULL;

$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `browser` WHERE name = '".$useragent."' LIMIT 0,1;";
$result = @mysql_query($query);

//  The browser is visiting the page for the first time
if (!$row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<!-- new browser -->";

    $query = "INSERT INTO `browser`
                (`id` ,`name`)
              VALUES
                (NULL ,'".$useragent."');";

    $result = @mysql_query($query);
}
//  The browser has already visited the page
else {
    echo "<!-- taken -->";
}
```

Now, it seems obvious to me that there is a SQL Injection on the $useragent parameter, but I can't able to exploit it, even with SQLMap.

If anyone could help, I would really thankful.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to all, I have just solved my problem. Next time I will be more self-confident.

I would like that someone deletes this message if it is possible. Otherwise, just forget it.

Sorry again.

Comment: Please do not post an answer without answering the question. Either explain how you fixed it or post your current answer as comment.